# reconnect with server each 5 seconds by dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i try to reconnect with the server , the connection established very well and it work every 5 sec very well also , but when i put a condiotn to control the conection it not working and still get new conection added , new connection added

how can i implement this by dart

```
var nbmer = 0;
  var channel;
  Timer? timer;

  connect() {
    Socket.connect(IP, PORT).then((Socket sock) async {
      channel = sock;
      sock.write('hello world'
          );
    });
  }

  try {
      if (nbmer == 0) {
        timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => connect());

       }
    } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
     }

    nbmer += 1;
```

Comment: Are You refresh the server?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your condition in the connect() function, because Timer.periodic will be periodically executed and not check your condition (if (nbmer == 0)).

**Solution**
Your code should look something like this:

```
  var nbmer = 0;
  var channel;
  Timer? timer;

  connect() {
    if (nbmer == 0) {
      nbmer += 1;
      Socket.connect(IP, PORT).then((Socket sock) async {
        channel = sock;
        sock.write('hello world');
      });
    }
  }

  try {
     timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) => connect());
  } catch(e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
```